# ¿Qué hace la instrucción this[int index] { get; set; }?

Tags: c#, asp.net, diseño-de-clases, this, indizador

Tengo la siguiente declaración de clase:

```
public class TD<TTDType>
{
    public TD();
    public TD(List<List<TTDType>> dataList);
    public List<TTDType> this[int index] { get; set; }
}
```

¿Qué hace la instrucción `this[int index] { get; set; }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso es un **indizador** y es útil para hacer más clara la sintaxis de acceso a objetos que pueden contener colecciones.

Explico con un ejemplo:

```
public class Estudiante
{
    int notas[] = new int[5];

    public int this [int indiceNotas]
    {
        get
        {
            return notas[indiceNotas];
        }
        set
        {
            notas[indiceNotas] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Y para usar este **indizador** harías:

```
Estudiante estudiante = new Estudiante();

estudiante[0] = 90;
estudiante[4] = 100;

Console.WriteLine(estudiante[4]);
```

Como ves usas el **objeto estudiante** como si fuera un arreglo a través de los corchetes **[]**, para introducir notas o mostrarlas.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda